# Forced domain for Rickshaw.js slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

We are currently displaying some graph with Rickshaw.js, in function of the time. This time can be in local time, or universal time.

The matter is: when we reduce the slider, then switch the time from local to universal (or the inverse), the slider also change its position.

I looked how the slider window was [determined](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/52867709195f71303e588c58b71a5aa6abb09f95/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider.js), but I don't see any ways to modify it...

Does someone have an idea ?

Thank you very much !